# Exclude a property from a schema [Swagger]

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I have a scheme `Foo` with the fields `a`, `b` and `c`. `c` is an array which is not returned when I do a `GET /foos`, but it is returned when I do `GET /foos/{foo_id}`.

How can I represent that with swagger scheme? (the `c` field being shown only when `GET`ing a specific `Foo`)

Comment: I think you need 2 different schemes for that return output.
Swagger is RESTful.  The idea is that the endpoints should return the same output scheme. Meaning: GET /foos should return an array of what ever /foos/{foo_id} returns.

With that said, you need to create a seperate scheme, for the different respons models

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a field in a definition required for some operations and not others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30895944/how-to-make-a-field-in-a-definition-required-for-some-operations-and-not-others)