# How to reuse swagger definitions and remove some of the parameters in it?

Tags: api, yaml, swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

This is my code:

```
definitions:
  User:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
      username:
        type: string
      first_name:
        type: string
      last_name:
        type: string
      password:
        type: string
      created_at:
        type: string
        format: date-time
      updated_at:
        type: string
        format: date-time
    required:
      - username
      - first_name
      - last_name
      - password

/api/users:
  post:
    description: Add a new user
    operationId: store
    parameters:
      - name: user
        description: User object
        in: body
        required: true
        type: string
        schema:
          $ref: '#/definitions/User'
    produces:
      - application/json
    responses:
      "200":
        description: Success
        properties:
          success:
            type: boolean
          data:
            $ref: '#/definitions/User'
```

As you can see, in the post key under `/api/users` I used the `User` definition as my schema on it.

I want to lessen my code so I reused the `User` definition as my schema. The problem here is that I do not need the `id`, `created_at` and `updated_at` fields.

Is there a way to just inherit some of the fields except the fields mentioned? Also, I would love some suggestions to make it better since I'm trying to learn swagger. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like `id`, `created_at` and `updated_at` are read-only and/or autogenerated properties. In this case you can just mark them as `readOnly: true` - as explained in the linked Q&A.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30895944/how-to-make-a-field-in-a-definition-required-for-some-operations-and-not-others) to a similar question:

> You would have to define the models separately.
>
> However, you have options for the cases of exclusion and difference.
>
> If you're looking to exclude, which is the easy case, create a model
>   of with the excluded property, say  `ModelA`. Then define `ModelB` as
>   `ModelA` plus the additional property:
>
> ```
> ModelB:
>   allOf:
>     - $ref: "#/definitions/ModelA"
>     - type: object
>       properties:
>         id:
>           type: string
> ```
>
> If you're looking to define the difference, follow the same method
>   above, and exclude the id from `ModelA`. Then define `ModelB` and `ModelC`
>   as extending `ModelA` and add the id property to them, each with its own
>   restrictions. Mind you, JSON Schema can allow you to follow the
>   original example above for some cases to "override" a definition.
>   However, since it is not really overriding, and one needs to
>   understand the concepts of JSON Schema better to not make simple
>   mistakes, I'd recommend going this path for now.

Comment: As seen in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30895944/how-to-make-a-field-in-a-definition-required-for-some-operations-and-not-others

Comment: Cool. I would not have seen that post without your suggestion. So that's the only way to do then. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome sir. I'm glad I could help