# Proper usage of OpenAPI 3.0.2

Tags: rest, openapi

I started using OpenAPI a few months ago, but I'm finding multiple caveats while generating documentation. This of course leads me to believe that I must be doing something wrong.

So, I usually begin always by creating the schemes for the multiple resources of my API, I then place a reference to the schemes on the request bodies for each respective endpoint. However I find that this approach makes generated documentation confusing, adding for example an `id` parameter on the request body of a user create operation when it's clearly not supposed to be there (*Of course the user is being created at this point, so there isn't even an ID in the first place, and why would an ID be part of the request body?*).

I ended up just making multiple schemes for a single data model, I would choose which one I used based on the operation (E.g. Creating vs Displaying), this way I could generate documentation more accurately. This helps me avoid situations like displaying relations that are generated post-creation on a create operation. (*I know I'm probably not phrasing all this correctly but just bear with me*).

In a nutshell, I'll end up with approximately 3 or 4 schemes per data model. For the `User` model I'll have for example `User`, `UserNew`, `UserSubscriptions`, `UserAll`. All schemes represent the same resource, they just differ in the data that they display.

Again, I feel like this is not the way that OpenAPI is meant to be used. So I hoped that maybe someone here that has more experience with this could guide me on the right path! Thank you.

Comment: Do these link answer your questions? [Re-using model with different required properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40839706/113116), [How to make a field in a definition required for some operations and not others](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30895944/113116). The examples there are for OpenAPI 2.0, but OAS3 uses the same approach.

Comment: In a way, yes, so I guess I do have to just make multiple models. But I did not know about the `readOnly` property! This will solve a good chunk of the problem. For now I will go on with this. Thank you.  If you'd like, respond to the question so I can mark it as the answer.